# Tiling problem in krita

Tags: tiles

Can't upload GIF because of file size limit, shows up "file not supported when adding imgur link so here's the GIF explaining my problem:- [Tiling problem krita](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC8xd.jpg)

As you can see the original texture tiles fine when using the "Wrap Around" mode but when I try to copy and paste the selection, it suddenly cuts off at the corner and doesn't tile. I would appreciate if the problem can be solved within krita itself, but I am also willing to accept the solution to the problem using alternative software such as GIMP if all fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is because you still have a selection made

To fix it, click *Select > Deselect*, after pasting, then move the artwork.

See this example

[image]